GraphQl function in zoho flow
I am trying to make a function to make a call in graphql to my shopify site via zoho flow with a deluge function my code works but I have the impression that the deluge poses certain problems in my code
Thank you for your help
headers = Map();
headers.put("X-Shopify-Access-Token",v_AccessToken);
headers.put("Content-Type","application/json");
// Construire dynamiquement le corps de la requête GraphQL
query = "{ companies(first: 1, query: \"external_id:'" + externalId + "'\") { edges { node { id name defaultRole { id name } contacts(first: 1, query: \"email:" + email + "\") { edges { node { id title isMainContact customer { id lastName firstName email } __typename } } } locations(first: 1) { nodes { id name catalogs(first: 1) { nodes { title } } } } } } }";
body = "{\"query\": \"{" + query + "}\"}";
// Requête GraphQL à Shopify
response = postUrl("https://dev-speechi-partenaire.myshopify.com/admin/api/2024-07/graphql.json",{"headers":headers,"body":body});
// Convertir la réponse en map
response_map = response.toMap();
// Affichage de la réponse complète de l'API
info response_map;
}

I'm looking to find a solution to make this code work in deluge

It is recommended to use invoke URL, since postURL will be deprecated.
See below a working example, you can adjust to your query needs.
query = {
    "query": "{ shop { name } }" 
};

query_json = query.toString();

get_shopify_shop_name = invokeurl 
[ 
url : "https://dev-speechi-partenaire.myshopify.com/admin/api/2024-07/graphql.json" 
type :POST 
content-type: "application/json"  
parameters :query_json 
connection :"shopify"

];

info get_shopify_shop_name;

In your code I see you are not using connections, I highly recommend it, as it is more secured and saves a lot of development time.
